# Python asyncio and pipelines

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using Python's `asyncio` to speed up the process of calling an API for multiple inputs concurrently.
For example:

```
tasks=[]
outputs=[]
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
     for input in inputs:
           tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(getsomething(input)))
     outputs = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`
```

The above code ensures that the `getsomething` method is called for every input, and I finally get the output from all tasks in one go.

What if, at the same time I would like to build a pipeline in which a second API can be called as soon as I get a response from one of the calls to the first endpoint?
Can somebody provide any pointers to implement it?

I am new to `asyncio` and the maximum I could get to was gathering all details and initiate one more for loop with all outputs from call to the first API.

Comment: Trivially, call something which in turn calls `getsomething` and then processes the result.

Comment: slightly less trivially, use a queue and when something comes back, push it into the queue for ```getsomething``` to handle.